# iOS Memory Leak Advice

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray

I'm pretty sure this is causing a leak and I would like some advice.  Here's code based on what I'm doing:

```
NSMutableArray* straVideoTitles;

- (void) parseData{
  //stuff
  straVideoTitles = [self getVideoTitle:strData]; //strData contains unparsed data
  //more stuff
}

- (NSMutableArray*) getVideoTitles:(NSString*)strData{
    NSMutableArray *array;
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //Parse data and populate array
    return array;
}
```

Based on the fact that I'm allocating space for NSMutableArray and not releasing it, thats a leak right?  How do I tackle this?  Should I forgo returning a value and assign straVideoTitles inside getVideoTitles then release like:

```
- (void) getVideoTitles:(NSString*)strData{
    NSMutableArray *array;
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //Parse data and populate array
    straVideoTitles = array;
    [array release];
}
```

or am i going about this all wrong?  Or is everything fine because I'm releasing straVideoTitles in dalloc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the

```
return array;
```

into

```
return [array autorelease];
```

Or you could use ARC and just don't care about it anymore.

Edit: The second approach is possible and does not include a memory leak but the code is less capsulated and therefore less reusable and future prove.

Answer (score 2):

Change to

`return [array autorelease];`

Answer (score 2):

It is good practice to return autorelease objects from methods. This is called a deferred release message.

You are relinquishing ownership while allowing the caller of the method to use the returned array before it is deallocated.

Your return statement should read:

```
return [array autorelease];
```

For more information on memory management take a look here:

[Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH)